# How to show tooltip for entered text in HTML without using JS

Tags: html, dynamic, input, tooltip, title

How to show the value present in an HTML `inputbox` as a `tooltip` when user hover over the cursor? I am using `title` attribute but how does that show the value for `dynamically` entered text?

I am new to HTML and I dont want to use JS/JQ. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you show in a tooltip something that is present in the element itself? What do you mean by “dynamically entered text” if it is not generated by JavaScript (which you don’t want to use)? Any server-side generation should be able to generate a `title` attribute, too.

Comment: It's a pity you don't want to use Javascript. With a bit of native/vanilla JS, an extremely intuitive and lightweight tooltip code is possible. Works in IE8 (possibly lower) and up and in all other browsers. If you would be interested in that after all, let me know and I will post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/367Aq/1/

**CSS :**

```
    [data-tips] {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    [data-tips]:after,
    [data-tips]:before {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: 0;
    }
        [data-tips]:after {
            content: attr(data-tips);
            height: 25px;
            line-height: 25px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            background: #222;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            white-space: nowrap;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        [data-tips]:before {
            content: "";
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-width: 6px;
            border-style: solid;
        }
            [data-tips]:hover:after,
            [data-tips]:hover:before {
                opacity: 1;
            }
/* Top tips */
[data-tips].top-tip:after,
[data-tips].top-tip:before {
    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    bottom: 90%;
    left: -9999px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
    [data-tips].top-tip:before {
        border-color: #222 transparent transparent transparent;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].top-tip:hover:after,
    [data-tips].top-tip:hover:before {
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].top-tip:hover:before {
        left: 15px;
    }
/* Bottom tip */
[data-tips].bottom-tip:after,
[data-tips].bottom-tip:before {
    -webkit-transition: top 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    top: 90%;
    left: -9999px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
    [data-tips].bottom-tip:before {
        border-color: transparent transparent #222 transparent;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].bottom-tip:hover:after,
    [data-tips].bottom-tip:hover:before {
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].bottom-tip:hover:before {
        left: 15px;
    }
/* Left tip */
[data-tips].left-tip:after,
[data-tips].left-tip:before {
    -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: left 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    top: -9999px;
    left: 96%;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
    [data-tips].left-tip:before {
        border-color: transparent #222 transparent transparent;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].left-tip:hover:after,
    [data-tips].left-tip:hover:before {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].left-tip:hover:before {
        top: 7px;
    }
/* Right tip */
[data-tips].right-tip:after,
[data-tips].right-tip:before {
    -webkit-transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    top: -9999px;
    right: 96%;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
    [data-tips].right-tip:before {
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #222;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].right-tip:hover:after,
    [data-tips].right-tip:hover:before {
        right: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    [data-tips].right-tip:hover:before {
        top: 7px;
    }
```

**HTML :**

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="top-tip" data-tips="Go to example.com">example.com</a>
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution!